# Enabling Device Emulation in Chrome without opening Dev Tools before

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use Device Emulation in Chrome several times in a raw daily for dozens of tabs.

Is there a way to enable/disable Device Emulation through a Shortcut or not, **without** having Dev Tools opened before ?

Not even having Dev Tools undocked into a separated window.